# SQL query returns student id, course section id, and grade when section id 1000

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-apex

Using Oracle Apex Browser, image of database
https://i.stack.imgur.com/E1bYR.jpg

```
select s_ID, c_sec_ID, grade
from s_ID.ID, c_sec_ID.csID, grade.ID, grade.csID
where c_sec_ID = 1000
```

^ All I think of and I'm not sure if I'm suppose to join them together or group them either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to join these tree tables `COURSE_SECTION`, `ENROLLMENT` and `STUDENT` to get desired output. Put `INNER JOIN` on three tables and add 
Where Clause to filter records.

You can try this

```
SELECT S.s_ID, C.c_sec_ID, E.grade    
FROM COURSE_SECTION C INNER JOIN ENROLLMENT E ON C.C_SEC_ID = E.C_SEC_ID
INNER JOIN STUDENT S ON S.S_ID = E.S_ID
WHERE  C.C_SEC_ID = 1000
```

Comment: I love you man it works! I had notes related to this but I didn't have the database picture of the code so I was a bit confused. Cleared some things up <3

Comment: Make this as Practice, if somebody Answer your question and that solved your problem, Then do not forget to Accept as Answer. This also help you to gain reputation and grow here. Thanks

Comment: Follow this site patterns and Ask another question, i will definitively help you.